# How do I trun off the menu .main-navigation using media equries

Tags: wordpress, menu, responsive-design, wordpress-theming

I am using the wordpress  [twenty twelve theme](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentytwelve/)

I am unable to turn off the menu at 800 px, using media queries.

[my site](http://hallmusicstudio.phinhall.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting in your `style.css`

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {

    .menu-main-menu-container{
        display:none;
    }

}
```

This will make the main menu 'disappear' under 800px window width.